# Ora not a valid month error while inserting into table

Tags: oracle, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I want to insert records in oracle table with my below stored procedure

Below is the procedure

Also below is the description of the table..

```
ID                            NOT NULL NUMBER         
CMP                                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
SAP_ID                                 NVARCHAR2(100) 
ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE                      DATE           
RRH_COUNTCHANGE                        NVARCHAR2(100) 
RRH_CHANGEDDATE                        DATE           
TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE                    NVARCHAR2(100) 
TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE                    DATE           
RFS_DATE                               DATE           
RFE1_DATE                              DATE           
INFRA_PROVIDER                         NVARCHAR2(100) 
IP_COLO_SITEID                         NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_NAME                              NVARCHAR2(500) 
R4GSTATE                               NVARCHAR2(100) 
MW_INSTALLED                           NVARCHAR2(100) 
DG_NONDG                               NVARCHAR2(100) 
EB_NONEB                               NVARCHAR2(100) 
TOWER_TYPE                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
VENDOR_CODE                            NVARCHAR2(100) 
RFCDATE                                DATE           
POLITICAL_STATE_NAME                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
POLITICAL_STATE_CODE                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_DROP_DATE                         DATE           
CITY_NAME                              NVARCHAR2(100) 
NEID                                   NVARCHAR2(100) 
FACILITY_LATITUDE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
FACILITY_LONGITUDE                     NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE                      NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_JC_NAME                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
RJ_JC_CODE                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
COMPANY_CODE                           NVARCHAR2(100) 
BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_MASTER                NVARCHAR2(100) 
BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_MASTER               NVARCHAR2(100) 
SITE_ADDRESS                           CLOB           
BLCHAIN_RESP_MSG_INCREMENTAL           VARCHAR2(100)  
BLCHAIN_RESP_CODE_INCREMENTAL          VARCHAR2(100)  
CREATED_BY                             NVARCHAR2(100) 
CREATED_DATE                           DATE           
SEL_CHANGED_VAL                        NVARCHAR2(100)
```

Please suggest what is wrong here.

**UPDATE**

```
PROCEDURE INSERT_IPCOLO_DATA
(
     P_SAPID IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_R4GSTATE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_POLITICAL_STATE_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_POLITICAL_STATE_CODE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_CMP IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_SITE_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_RFC_DATE IN DATE,     
     P_RFE1_DATE IN DATE,
     P_SITE_DROP_DATE IN DATE,
     P_INFRA_PROVIDER IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_IPCOLO_SITEID IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_IPSAP_VENDORCODE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_MW_INSTALLED IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_DG_AVAILABLE IN NVARCHAR2,     
     P_EB_AVAILABLE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_TOWER_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE IN DATE,
     P_RRH_COUNTCHANGE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE IN DATE,
     P_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE IN DATE,     
     P_CITY_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_NEID IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_FAC_LATITUDE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_FAC_LONGITUDE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_RJ_STRUC_TYPE IN NVARCHAR2,     
     P_RJ_JC_NAME IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_RJ_JC_CODE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_COMPANY_CODE IN NVARCHAR2,     
     P_CREATED_BY IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_CHANEDVALUE IN NVARCHAR2,
     P_RFS_DATE IN DATE,
     TBL_INSERT OUT NUMBER
)

AS 

vr_RRH_COUNTCHANGE nvarchar2(100);
vr_RRH_CHANGEDDATE date;
vr_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE nvarchar2(100);
vr_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE date;
vr_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE nvarchar2(100);
vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE date;


BEGIN

    IF P_CHANEDVALUE = 'IDOD'

    THEN
      BEGIN

          vr_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE:= P_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE;
           vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE:=P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE;

          /* P_RRH_COUNTCHANGE :='';
           P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE :='';
           P_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE :='';
           P_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE :='';      */
           vr_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE:= null;
           vr_RRH_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_RRH_CHANGEDDATE:=null;

      END;
      END IF;

      IF P_CHANEDVALUE = 'RRH'

    THEN
      BEGIN

        /*   P_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE :='';
           P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE :='';
           P_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE :='';
           P_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE :=''; */   

           vr_RRH_COUNTCHANGE:=P_RRH_COUNTCHANGE;
           vr_RRH_CHANGEDDATE:=P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE;

           vr_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE:= null;
           vr_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE:=null;

      END;
      END IF;

      IF P_CHANEDVALUE = 'Tenancy'

    THEN
      BEGIN

        /*   P_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE :='';
           P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE :='';
           P_RRH_COUNTCHANGE :='';
           P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE :='';  */

           vr_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE:=P_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE;
           vr_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE:= P_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE;

           vr_RRH_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_RRH_CHANGEDDATE:=null;
           vr_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE:=null;

      END;
      END IF;

      INSERT INTO TBL_IPCOLO_BILLING_MST
                                      (
                                         SAP_ID,
                                         R4GSTATE,
                                         POLITICAL_STATE_NAME,
                                         POLITICAL_STATE_CODE,
                                         CMP,
                                         SITE_NAME,
                                         RFCDATE,
                                         RFE1_DATE,
                                         SITE_DROP_DATE,
                                         INFRA_PROVIDER,
                                         IP_COLO_SITEID,
                                         VENDOR_CODE,
                                         MW_INSTALLED,
                                         DG_NONDG,     
                                         EB_NONEB,
                                         TOWER_TYPE,
                                         ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
                                         ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,
                                         RRH_COUNTCHANGE,
                                         RRH_CHANGEDDATE,
                                         TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE,
                                         TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE,     
                                         CITY_NAME,
                                         NEID,
                                         FACILITY_LATITUDE,
                                         FACILITY_LONGITUDE,
                                         RJ_STRUCTURE_TYPE,     
                                         RJ_JC_NAME,
                                         RJ_JC_CODE,
                                         COMPANY_CODE,     
                                         CREATED_BY,
                                         CREATED_DATE,
                                         SEL_CHANGED_VAL,
                                         RFS_DATE                                         
                                      )
    VALUES                           (

                                        P_SAPID,
                                       P_R4GSTATE,
                                       P_POLITICAL_STATE_NAME,
                                       P_POLITICAL_STATE_CODE,
                                       P_CMP,
                                       P_SITE_NAME,
                                       P_RFC_DATE,     
                                       P_RFE1_DATE,
                                       P_SITE_DROP_DATE,
                                       P_INFRA_PROVIDER,
                                       P_IPCOLO_SITEID,
                                       P_IPSAP_VENDORCODE,
                                       P_MW_INSTALLED,
                                       P_DG_AVAILABLE,     
                                       P_EB_AVAILABLE,
                                       P_TOWER_TYPE,
                                       vr_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE,
                                       vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,
                                       vr_RRH_COUNTCHANGE,
                                       vr_RRH_CHANGEDDATE,
                                       vr_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE,
                                       vr_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE,     
                                       P_CITY_NAME,
                                       P_NEID,
                                       P_FAC_LATITUDE,
                                       P_FAC_LONGITUDE,
                                       P_RJ_STRUC_TYPE,     
                                       P_RJ_JC_NAME,
                                       P_RJ_JC_CODE,
                                       P_COMPANY_CODE,     
                                       P_CREATED_BY,
                                       SYSDATE,
                                       P_CHANEDVALUE,
                                     P_RFS_DATE                                
                                    );

TBL_INSERT := 0;



END INSERT_IPCOLO_DATA;
```

**CODE**

```html
public static string INSERT_IPCOLO_DATA(IPColoFields IPColoFields)
        {
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_IPCOLO"].ConnectionString);
            string intRetId = "";
            try
            {
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PackageName"].ToString() + ".INSERT_IPCOLO_DATA";
                cmd.Connection = conn;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_SAPID", Value = IPColoFields.SAP_ID, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_R4GSTATE", Value = IPColoFields.R4GSTATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_POLITICAL_STATE_NAME", Value = IPColoFields.POLITICAL_STATE_NAME, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_POLITICAL_STATE_CODE", Value = IPColoFields.POLITICAL_STATE_CODE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_CMP", Value = IPColoFields.CMP, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_SITE_NAME", Value = IPColoFields.SITE_NAME, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RFC_DATE", Value = IPColoFields.RFC_DATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RFE1_DATE", Value = IPColoFields.RFE1_DATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_SITE_DROP_DATE", Value = IPColoFields.SITE_DROP_DATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_INFRA_PROVIDER", Value = IPColoFields.INFRA_PROVIDER, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_IPCOLO_SITEID", Value = IPColoFields.IPCOLO_SITEID, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_IPSAP_VENDORCODE", Value = IPColoFields.IPSAP_VENDORCODE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_MW_INSTALLED", Value = IPColoFields.MW_INSTALLED, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_DG_AVAILABLE", Value = IPColoFields.DG_AVAILABLE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_EB_AVAILABLE", Value = IPColoFields.EB_AVAILABLE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_TOWER_TYPE", Value = IPColoFields.TOWER_TYPE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE", Value = IPColoFields.ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE", Value = IPColoFields.ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RRH_COUNTCHANGE", Value = IPColoFields.RRH_COUNTCHANGE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE", Value = IPColoFields.ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE", Value = IPColoFields.TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE", Value = IPColoFields.TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_CITY_NAME", Value = IPColoFields.CITY_NAME, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_NEID", Value = IPColoFields.NEID, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_FAC_LATITUDE", Value = IPColoFields.FAC_LATITUDE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_FAC_LONGITUDE", Value = IPColoFields.FAC_LONGITUDE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RJ_STRUC_TYPE", Value = IPColoFields.RJ_STRUC_TYPE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RJ_JC_NAME", Value = IPColoFields.RJ_JC_NAME, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RJ_JC_CODE", Value = IPColoFields.RJ_JC_CODE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_COMPANY_CODE", Value = IPColoFields.COMPANY_CODE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_CREATED_BY", Value = IPColoFields.CREATED_BY, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_CHANEDVALUE", Value = IPColoFields.CHANGED_FIELDS, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter { ParameterName = "P_RFS_DATE", Value = IPColoFields.RFS_DATE, OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Date, Direction = ParameterDirection.Input });

                cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "TBL_INSERT",
                    OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Decimal,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                });

                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                intRetId = cmd.Parameters["TBL_INSERT"].Value.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
            }

            return intRetId;
        }
```

Comment: Is this bit a typo? `to_date(P_RFS_DATE,'-dd-mm-yyyy')` ... should it be `to_date(P_RFS_DATE,'dd-mm-yyyy'`?

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264: let me check again

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264: the error still persist

Comment: Values `P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE`, `P_RFC_DATE`, `P_RFE1_DATE` , `P_SITE_DROP_DATE`, `P_RFS_DATE` are `DATE` values. Why do you run `TO_DATE()` on a value which is already a DATE?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: I changed by removing To_DATE() function but still getting the error as `ORA-1843: not a valid month`

Comment: Did you remove **all** `TO_DATE` calls?

Comment: Why do you have so many `NVARCHAR2` columns? Do they all contain special Unicode characters?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: yes removed all the date calls, but is it may be due to other date columns which are going nulls ? for ex: here `vr_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE:=P_TENANCY_COUNTCHANGE;
           vr_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE:= P_TENANCY_CHANGEDDATE;
           
           vr_RRH_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_RRH_CHANGEDDATE:=null;
           vr_ID_OD_COUNTCHANGE:='';
           vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE:=null;`

Comment: I assume you have `DATE` columns but according input parameter is `NVARCHAR2` - in these cases you should use `TO_DATE`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200237/discussion-between-b-n-and-wernfried-domscheit).

Comment: Setting variable to `NULL` will never raise such exception. Where do you get the error?

Comment: I am just getting error as `ORA-1843: not a valid month`

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the code which is updated after implementing every changes that is suggested in the comment.

Comment: @Tejash: updated with latest code

Comment: **NEVER**, ever call `to_date()` on a value that is already a date. That will first convert the `date` value to a `varchar` just to convert that `varchar` back to a `date` which it was to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, i removed that..but still getting unwanted errors

Comment: Then you should only keep one copy of the procedure code in your question. If you have two similar versions this confuses people

Comment: How you call this procedure? It would be helpful if you paste that code also.

Comment: If you remove the insert statement, does the procedure still work?

Comment: @Boneist : didn’t check that way..we have holiday today here. Will update u tomorrow asap. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P_RFS_DATE` is a date. `RFS_DATE` is a date. So why are you treating `P_RFS_DATE` like a string that must be converted to a date here?

```
to_date(P_RFS_DATE,'-dd-mm-yyyy')
```

It must be just

```
P_RFS_DATE
```

instead. The same is true for the other four times you are applying `TO_DATE` in your procedure.

**UPDATE:** There are other places where you treat the dates like strings. Here for instance:

```
P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE :='';
```

Do you want null?

```
P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE := null;
```

As you are not seeing the full error message including the line number, you can select it:

```
select * from all_errors;
```

Comment: so every date coluimn needs to be added like that ?

Comment: Yes `TO_DATE` is made to convert a string to a date. You have dates, so don't convert. E.g. `vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE:=to_date(P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE,'dd-mm-yyyy');` must be `vr_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE := P_ID_OD_CHANGEDDATE;`

Comment: And the error message should tell you in which line the error occurs.

Comment: its just telling `ORA-1843: not a valid month`

Comment: Okay. I guess you have removed all five `TO_DATE` calls. I see now that there are other places where you treat the dates like strings. Here for instance: `P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE :='';` The name alone should tell you this is a date, so why are you trying to set it to an emppty string? What is this even supposed to mean? Maybe you want `P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE := null;`

Comment: i cant see date with `' '`.. can u help where it is

Comment: I don't understand. In line 60 you are setting the date `P_RRH_CHANGEDDATE` to an empty string (`:= ''`). But a date is a date, not a string. It's like saying "My favorite number is MOUSE". And please see my updated answer. `select * from all_errors` may help you to spot the errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200239/discussion-between-b-n-and-thorsten-kettner).